# Create Proxies in Azure

Tags: azure, proxy

Create proxies using Azure for a bot that i have developed. 
I'm creating a bot which utilizes proxies to buy merchandise of sites from back-end and i wanted to generate some proxies using Azure to mask my local IP. There are various services that offer the proxies (data center and residential proxies) for a little amount.

However, i would like to generate proxies  by myself using Azure. How can i create proxies and use it in my local application so websites believe that the request is coming from the proxy server?

I create few virtual VM's (two linux and two windows based). I tries using squid proxy to convert the VM into a proxy but since i do not have much knowledge on linux, i am facing multiple issues. Also, i am not understanding on how to proceed on the windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Functions to call proxies for App Services and OnPremise Servers:

Announcement:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/announcing-azure-functions-proxies-in-public-preview/

How To, Sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies